# How to troubleshoot macbook's failing parts

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

Not sure if its a software or hardware problem. When I turn on my macbook pro (2011) it asks me for a password, shows some progress bar after (it fills up to like 30%) and then it just reboots and starts the whole process again.

I tried all kinds of recovery methods (USB stick with repair tools, another USB stick with a fresh version of Yosemite, Internet recovery...) but I always end up at a grey screen and nothing is happening.

p.s. Apple hardware test says that everything is ok and no errors have been found.

Comment: does it boot in Safe mode ? to exclude any non apple apps!

Comment: also try starting in verbose mode to see how far does it get.

Answer (score 1):

Try [resetting the SMC](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT3964) and [resetting the PRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14222?viewlocale=en_US).

It's also possible that your hard drive is failing in such a way that the computer can't boot. I haven't seen that often but it can happen (if you hear weird clicking sounds on boot, that increases the likelihood of this being the case).

It's pretty easy to take the hard drive out of your computer (all you need is a a phillips-head #00), it may be worth removing the hard drive, then trying to boot to an external disk.

[MacBook Pro take-apart guides](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/MacBook_Pro).

Comment: I tried both SMC and PRAM already, just forgot to mention. I can actually hear weird clicking sound when I carry/tilt my laptop but its been like this since 2011 so probably its not the case.Anyways, thank you for your help I really appreciate it!

Comment: Did you try removing the hard drive? It does seem unlikely that the clicking is from your hard drive, more likely that something is stuck in the fan.